Placement of nucleons in the shell model for odd-even nuclei
The question I'm trying to answer is this:
What are the spin and parity predicted by the shell model for 37
20Ca (in order of increasing
energy the order of states is [1s1/2
, 1p3/2
, 1p1/2
][1d5/2
, 2s1/2
, 1d3/2
][1f7/2
, . . . with [] marking
the limits of well-separated shells)?
I understand that this is given by the odd nucleon (here the 17th neutron). As s-shells hold 2 nucleons, p-shells hold 6 and d-shells hold 10 I found that the first shell holds 2+6+6 = 14 neutrons, so there are 3 in the next shell. So shouldn't the odd neutron be in the 1d5/2 state? But the answer says it is in the 1d3/2 state and I can't understand how. Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I understand! 1p3/2 and 1p1/2 don't each have degeneracy 6, but rather a total degeneracy of 6 between them, with the degeneracy of each individual state given by 2J+1 (in this example 4 + 2 = 6). BY combining the states like this we get the expected answer. :)
